# Unable to find DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, selenium-webdriver, xpath

So I was writing some automated tests(C# and Selenium Webdriver) and came across a weird scenario.
The XPath Selector works fine(using an element id) when trying to identify an element in the Dev Tools DOM explorator, but when using the same id to find the element through jQuery selector or plain JS selector in the console, it returns a null.

Element ID: `"sample-id";`
Element type: `div`;
jQuery Selector: `$("div#sample-id")`;
JS Selector: `document.getElementById("sample-id")`;
Xpath: `"//div[contains(@id, 'sample-id')]"`;

Quick note: after waiting for a minute or so, the jQuery or JS selector works.

Any ideas to why this is happening?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include a sample of the selector in question and what you've tried.

Comment: As always, if a selector doesn't match an element, the element does not exist at the time it's been tried to retrieve.

Comment: The target element already exists in the DOM, when using any of the selectors. It is displayed and visible.

Comment: Did you try to *wait until element appeared in DOM*? Check whether element located inside `frame`/`iframe`

Comment: Indeed, just noticed, the element is within an iframe

Comment: If the element is within a frame the 'safest' way to access it is: `document.getElementById("iframe-id").contentDocument.document.getElementById("sample-id")`